# if condition not working with same $variable in php

Tags: php, if-statement

i have three array and all array have relation (like:`Date[0] Game[0] Data[0]`)

**Array in index format**

```
DATE     | GAME | DATA
17-12-14 | A    | 72
17-12-14 | B    | 16
17-12-14 | C    | 78
18-12-14 | A    | 45
18-12-14 | B    | 56
18-12-14 | C    | 89
```

**Now i want to get result like that**

```
DATE     | GAME | DATA
17-12-14 | C    | 78
18-12-14 | A    | 45
18-12-14 | B    | 56
```

**Here my code what i am tried**

```
    foreach ($date as $key => $value) {
    $dateSet=($dates[$key]);
    $gameSet=($games[$key]);
    $dataSet=($datas[$key]);

    if (($dateSet >= "17-12-14" ) &&($gameSet == "A") && ($gameSet == "B") && ($gameSet == "C")){
        echo $dateSet.'-'.$gameSet.'-'.$dataSet."<br />";
    }
    }
```

output A blank page :(

thank in advance

**Update**

```
    if (($dateSet >= "17-12-14" ) &&(($gameSet == "A")||($gameSet == "B")||($gameSet == "C"))){
        echo $dateSet.'-'.$gameSet.'-'.$dataSet."<br />";
    }
```

now output is all six rows . but i want only 17-12-14 C row and 18-12-14 A and B rows

Comment: If you are looking for help, you would probably get more results if you asked a specific detailed question. You're on the right track just try being more verbose with your request for help

Comment: you're not comparing dates. You're comparing **STRINGS**. `17-12-14` is presumably Dec 17/2014, which means that `31-11-14` will test out as LARGER than 17-12-14, because 31 > 17.

Comment: @Marc B point to be noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (($dateSet >= "17-12-14" ) &&($gameSet == "A") && ($gameSet == "B") && ($gameSet == "C")){
```

You require the variable $gameSet to be equal to A AND B AND C, which is of course impossible. You'll need to change your IF statement.
Possibly by using a few OR checks ->

```
 if (($dateSet >= "17-12-14" ) && (($gameSet == "A") || ($gameSet == "B") || ($gameSet == "C"))){
```

Comment: now output is all six rows . but i want only 17-12-14 C row and 18-12-14 A and B rows

Answer (score 1):

You're if statement is incorrect. Change to

(($dateSet >= "17-12-14" ) && (($gameSet == "A") || ($gameSet == "B") || ($gameSet == "C")))

Comment: now output is all six rows . but i want only 17-12-14 C row and 18-12-14 A and B rows